# Postgres Sanitization of Inputs Failure

Tags: postgresql, lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am building a simple API and part of the API is supposed to return all unique values for a given column from a PG database. This is all wrapped up in lambda functions using the serverless framework. All of the other APIs work except for this one, and when I manually enter queries into PG, they work. I'm not sure what's happening, any advice?

Failing API hit example: `/columnVals/?field=title`

```
const app = express();
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
  user: <USER>,
  password: <PASSWORD>,
  database: <DBNAME>,
  host: <DBURL>,
  port: <DBPORT>,
});

...

app.get("/columVals/", cors(), function (req, res) {
  var all_query = `SELECT DISTINCT $1 FROM database_archive;`;
  pool.query(all_query, [req.query.field], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    res.status(200).json(results.rows);
    let data = results.rows;
    data = data.map((a) => Object.values(a));
    data = data.flat().filter((n) => n);
    data = [...new Set(data)];
    res.status(200).json(data);
  });
});
```

For some reason this works though (this is obviously vulnerable to SQL injection which is why it isn't you used).

```
app.get("/columVals/", cors(), function (req, res) {
  var all_query = `SELECT DISTINCT ${req.query.field} FROM database_archive;`;
  pool.query(all_query, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    res.status(200).json(results.rows);
    let data = results.rows;
    data = data.map((a) => Object.values(a));
    data = data.flat().filter((n) => n);
    data = [...new Set(data)];
    res.status(200).json(data);
  });
});
```

The lambda function server error is a 500 code internal server error. My question is why the param is being sanitized such that it fails even when it doesn't pose an SQL injection attack threat.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say what language this is written in. I'm assuming some Javascript variant.

You also don't bother to post the actual output from your incorrect function. That would have been useful and probably would have saved you from posting the question at all.

In your first example you are using paramter placeholders. This is *not* simple string substitution - it is like passing parameters to a function. It is used for values and not for structural elements of your query (like column or table names).

So in your first example you are asking for `SELECT DISTINCT <literal value> FROM  <table whose values are not used>`.

Since you don't know the difference between your two examples and this appears to be accessible from the general internet I urge you to read up on "SQL injection" and review your code as soon as possible.

Your second example leaves your entire database accessible to anyone who can post a request to that endpoint.

Comment: A little unecessary on the aggression, the output of the server is "Internal Server Error", the code is clearly javascript (I should've clarified though) and I am intimately familiar with SQL injection attacks (I've even written them before). Obviously the second one leaves this vulnerability which is why I don't use it.

That being said, thank you for the point you made on literal values. Please temper your answers so people who are new to the technology community don't leave it.

Comment: "Internal Server Error" isn't a useful level of error even at the second attempt is it? Nor is the code clearly Javascript because... I'm not a web developer, I'm a database developer. That "=>" isn't something I remember from the little javascript I used to do a decade ago. And for the love of god if you know code is dangerous what were you doing posting it on a question + answer site where thousands of beginners can stumble across it? And if you know the difference between query parameter substitution and string interpolation why were you posting the question?

Comment: if you don't have enough details please don't answer, ask for clarification/vote to close

Comment: The extra information wasn't for my benefit, it was for the benefit of the OP (who wouldn't have had to ask if he'd drilled down to what was actually happening in the database). Voting to close just kills his question and leaves his problem unsolved.